# nginx: Why is previous stable version showing after installing from sources?

Tags: 18.04, nginx

I'm working to install nginx version `1.17.7` from sources. I am using a vanilla instance running Ubuntu 18.04 that does not have nginx installed. Why do I see version `1.14.0` installed? I would expect to see version `1.17.7`.

```
nginx -V;
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-DUghaW/nginx-1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module
```

The commands I run are:

```
# Get the latest version of nginx.
$ wget https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.17.7.tar.gz

# Extract
$ tar -zxvf nginx-1.17.7.tar.gz;

# Configure
$ cd nginx-1.17.7;
$ ./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-pcre --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-http_ssl_module --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --with-http_v2_module --user=www --group=www

# Make and install
$ make;
$ sudo make install;

# Verify the install worked.
$ ls -l /etc/nginx;
$ nginx -V;
```

Comment: This means that you didn't build anything, but you have installed nginx from Ubuntu repos. Did you read output of the commands? You can check by `apt policy nginx`.

Comment: Have you restarted the NGINX process yet?  Did you actually *install* NGINX yet?  Did you previously install NGINX from the repositories?

Comment: @Pilot6, I've updated comments to include command output. Does this help?

Comment: @ThomasWard, I've run the command `systemctl reload nginx`. No, I didnt previously install nginx. I am started with a vanilla instance of Ubuntu which. I have not used the apt package manager either.

Comment: So run `/usr/bin/nginx -V`

Comment: And can you post output of `which nginx`?

Comment: Interesting, I see the version I am looking for. ```nginx version: nginx/1.17.7
built by gcc 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-pcre --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-http_ssl_module --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp ...```

Comment: `which nginx`: /usr/sbin/nginx

Comment: So you have nginx 1.14 installed from Ubuntu repos. You are lying that it is not installed ;-)

Comment: Ha, yeah, I guess i am. I thought it was not installed. Could this mean i need to change a symlink?

Comment: You have both installed. One in `/usr/bin` the other in `/usr/sbin`

Comment: Based on your last comment, I started investigating why I had nginx installed in two locations. I was installing the `python-certbot-nginx` package for certbot before installing nginx. I'm not absolutely certain, but it appears that is what is installing the other version of nginx...likely from the package manager. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so i can accept it?